# XAML ProgressRing doesn't stop

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm, windows-runtime

My problem is that ProgressRing is running all the time. I use MVVM. ProgressRing could be active only when app get new data.

I have code in VM (I updated ViewModel):

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ObservableCollection<AdModel>, ISupportIncrementalLoading{
    private Visibility _loaderVisibility;
    public Visibility LoaderVisibility
    {
        get { return _loaderVisibility; }
        private set
        {
            _loaderVisibility = value;

        }}
    public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
    {
        CoreDispatcher coreDispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;

        return Task.Run<LoadMoreItemsResult>(async () =>
        {
            await coreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                () =>
                {
                    this.LoaderVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
                });

            var NewAds = new ObservableCollection<AdModel>();

            do{NewAds = await LoadAds();//get data from API}
            while (NewAds == null);

            await coreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                () =>
                {
                    foreach (AdModel item in NewAds)
                    {
                        this.Add(item);
                    }
                    this.LoaderVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                });

            return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = count };
        }).AsAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult>();}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to fire the `PropertyChanged` event when you change the `LoaderVisibility` property, so that UI can be notified of the new value. See an example on how to [Implement Property Change Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.100).aspx).

The LoaderVisibility property should look like this (this VM class needs to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, so you have the `PropertyChanged` event).

```
private Visibility _loaderVisibility; 
public Visibility LoaderVisibility 
{
    get { return _loaderVisibility; }
    set 
    {
        _loaderVisibility = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("LoaderVisibility"));
    }
}
```

Second, do not set the `ProgressRing's Visibility` property from code behind, that will break the data binding you wire up in XAML.

Comment: My class inherits from ObservableCollection so implements this interface. Your solution not working, I have: "The event 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -="

Comment: Can you paste the code of the whole `VM` class? Remove the irrelevant properties.

Comment: Udpated. I removed XAML and code behind because a lot of code.

Comment: ProgressRing works all the time but Visibility is changed in the right moment. I don't know..

Comment: Wait a minute...you mean your problem is not about showing/hiding the ProgressRing, but to start/stop it?

Comment: I mean showing/hiding. ProgressRing shows all the time.

Comment: Have you removed the line that you set in C# code: `ProgressRing.Visibility = Collection.LoaderVisibility;`?

Comment: No, how do I binding data to the view with my VM?

Comment: You need to remove that line. In your originally posted code, the binding is already done in XAML: `<ProgressRing x:Name="ProgressRing" Visibility="{Binding LoaderVisibility}"`, right? If you set the Visibility property again in C# code, the binding will not work.

Comment: It's work when I bind VM object to ListView.ItemSource and to DataContext separately. How do this more true? Edit: I bind only DataContext, ListView.ItemSource={Binding} and in Visibility Visibility="{Binding LoaderVisibility} Works fine :)

Comment: Oh, congrats you have finally made it work, that is another problem besides the two I address in my answer. You can find the differences between `ItemsSource` and `DataContext` from other posts.